# Browser rendered URL and Scraped URL are different. Please explain

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I am new to the world of web scraping,Python and Scrapy. So pardon me if there is some fundamental flaw in my understanding. I come from a JAVA/R background. I am trying to scrape [www.amazon.in](http://www.amazon.in) for book details. I built the XPATHs required after using chrome's XPATH finder, but when I try the same XPATH query in Scrapy shell a different form of the URL is being displayed.

for example for the following XPATH query `//ul[@id='ref_976390031']/li[23]/a[@href]/@href` in the XPATH finder I get

`www.amazon.in/s/ref=lp_976389031_nr_n_21?fst=as%3Aoff&rh=n%3A976389031%2Cn%3A%21976390031%2Cn%3A1318203031&bbn=976390031&ie=UTF8&qid=1418660681&rnid=976390031`

But when I try it on the response variable of the scrapy shell as `response.xpath("//ul[@id='ref_976390031']/li[23]/a[@href]/@href").extract()`

I get

```
http://www.amazon.in/b?ie=UTF8&node=1318203031
```

What's more interesting is, the **scraped** link when keyed into a browser lands in a different page as opposed to the page where its supposed to land( Same behaviour i.e. landing in a different pages occurs when **scraped** too)

One more thing I have observed, while **scraping** though the links **scraped** are different from the browser rendered links most of them are directed/redirected properly, While some links like this dont.

This behaviour makes my **scraper** scrape successfully on some links and some links are not **scraped** at all.

Any help/explanation for this behaviour will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1) scrapy will not execute the javascript, but the browser does, so the changes may be caused by the javascript. (for the case, phantomjs may helps) 2) some website will response different content by different UserAgent

Comment: But some links do work correctly, also I have tried the same xpath on both Chrome and mozilla the redirection/query result/manual path tracing is perfect!

Comment: how about `wget` the html file, and check the @href directly to check is the javascript does the different.

Comment: it's because you are using diffrent user agents.

Comment: @kyle K, can you pls explain a little more and also what do u think needs to be done to standardize it ?

Comment: Some web-sites look at cookies, user-agent, JS-support to adjust the returned page.

Comment: @warvariuc Yes, But how can some scraped links still redirect correctly and only a few cannot ?

Comment: It's server logic that you have to research yourself, unfortunately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kyle K,warvariuc were right, the site was rendering different URLs for different user agents.

Adding the following parameter in `settings.py`fixed the issue

```
USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1207.1 Safari/537.1"
```

Thank you everyone for taking the time to reply.